# Azure Application Gateway for hosting an e-commerce website on Azure

Tags: ssl-certificate, web-applications

Actually I have two questions about Azure Application Gateway:
1. If I want to host a website on Azure, is it necessary to get an SSL certificate ? or does Azure provide it ?
2. If not necessary, Can I use the Application Gateway only as a Web Application Firewall ?

Answer (score 0):

1 will depend on where the back end will "live" - Web App, Virtual Machine, Blob Storage Account through CDN.

As for 2, App gateway is an application load balancer or what used to be called application delivery controller of which web application firewalling is one feature.

App gateway will receive and route traffic to a backend pool of servers, storage accounts or web services.

So a lot will depend on what exactly you want to achieve.